# Permanently Delete Empty Rows using JAVA in Excel Sheet

Tags: java

I  need a help to delete entire empty row in excel using java. If anyone knows please help me. I tried with removerow() in apache poi , but i want to delete the entire row

Comment: what have you allready tried, pleas post some code. Excel files can have different format, which one do you have. Why java and python?

Comment: Fascinating story. Do you have a question?

Comment: Post a specific query. Yours is too generic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apachi POI for manipulating excel files in Java. For removing a row you can use its removeRow() method, and for deleting empty rows you can use its unshift() method.

Below is an example where we have a list of all the row numbers which we want to remove from our sheet. It will also delete the row, and remove the empty white spaces.

```
ArrayList<Integer> rowNumbersToDelete = // Contains all row numbers to delete

        for (int rowNo : rowNumbersToDelete)
        {
            Row row = firstSheet.getRow(rowNo);
            firstSheet.removeRow(row);
            int lastIndex = firstSheet.getLastRowNum();
            firstSheet.shiftRows(rowNo + 1, lastIndex, -1);
        }
```

Comment: can u please share me some examples if u are having?